# Web Application with different URLs for different Users

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, struts2, restful-url

I want to create a Struts2 Web Application with a functionality like:

- if user A is logging in, then he can access the application like

  ```
  http://product.com/a/login.jsp
  ```
- if user B is logging in, then

  ```
  http://product.com/b/login.jsp
  ```

and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Is it good to do this? or can I use Subdomain?

Comment: *if A is purchased application then he can access application like http://product.com/a/login.jsp*: EEH ?

Comment: its like Gmail. If you have gmail login then you can login with yourloginname@gmail.com. and if you have your company.. then you can login with that also.. like username@company.com

Both time after login check url. url will be the different and data will be different but layout and look is same.!

Comment: Then A and B are users, and your sentence is "If A HAS purchased the application...?"

Comment: Yaah mistakes are changed! Can you have my question's answer?

Comment: @JayPatel All URLs are mapped via the configuration, either you use xml or annotations based configuration it do it's job. Wildcards could be used there to generalize those mappings, in any ways it point to a class which instance is managed by the container and an invocation is applied to the interceptor stacks, but even if you supply the valid configuration how would the instance know wich user it should map to?

Comment: @RomanC I want to know the same. Actually If I configured REST then still how would I know for which user I need to fetch Data?

Comment: @JayPatel Until user is not identified you can't make any decisions. Puting an interceptor in front of the user possible to redirect to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't work like that: in GMail (that you've taken as example) every user will always be redirected, after the log-in, to the same location:

> **https://mail.google.com/mail/**

If you enable the **Google Multiple Sign-In**, they will store separately the different log-in credentials server side, and will use different cookies client-side, with the same name but different paths:

Cookie for 1st account login:

```
Name    : S 
Content : gmail=someRandomHash
Server  : mail.google.com
Path    : /mail/u/0
```

Cookie for 2nd account login:

```
Name    : S 
Content : gmail=someRandomHash
Server  : mail.google.com
Path    : /mail/u/1
```

Then, when switching from one account to another, they will redirect you to a different URL:

1st account mailbox URL

> **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/**

2nd account mailbox URL

> **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/**

Once authenticated on both of them, you can manually switch between your different mailboxes by simply accessing the relative URL (try, if you have multiple accounts).

Conclusions: Google use different Rest URLs (with a named variable, in this case `u`: user) to differentiate multiple accounts... for the same PC. 
The added value is that you can switch between your multiple accounts without the need to log-out of the first and log-in to the second *every time*.

This has nothing to do with separating the URLs to handle different accounts ON DIFFERENT COMPUTERS.

Comment: Actually my application for Hospitals for a state.in state many hospitals are there.So at the login time I need to provide hospital combo.doctor will select hospital and then login.But I don't won't to provide hospital's list at login page.that's why I want to do like this!.And I don't know much about this scenario.So,What should I do? either subdomain or URL?

Comment: You should mantain (in your database) a list of tuples {ID_AUTH,ID_HOSPITAL} , and check it in an entry-point page, to decode which hospital you need to load for each loggedin user. ID_AUTH is a reference to the row containing the login information for each user (eg. ID_AUTH, USERNAME, ONE-WAY-HASHED-PASSWORD), while ID_HOSPITAL is the ID to the row of the hospital, that you should have in your backend. This kind of informations should be mantained by another backoffice webapp, or another, "admin" section of your webapp, or by putting them manually into the database.

Comment: You are welcome. As a final note, the REST behavior you was describing (with the username in the URL) is more like StackOverflow, but that is useful when you should be able to see the other users, no matter if you are logged in or if it's your page; in your case, just put your details in session by matching them in the first action, and use an custom Interceptor (to check if the user info are in session) on all the other actions... if not, redirect to the first. [Like described here](http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/08/struts2-write-your-own-interceptor-for.html),with obj instead of a bool

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a filter then check the request and redirect to the correct view.

Do not use which deprecated according to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3742:

```
    FilterDispatcher(Deprecated)
```

I suggest:

```
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

First as I said you will need the request:

```
  HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

Then find the request URL like this:

```
  String spath = request.getServletPath();
```

Now you parse your URL, and after forward to the correct view(pages: jsp, html...)

Comment: Do I need to check this for each action called? actually my layout and view pages will be the same for all.I am creating one web product which have 1000s of client.so asking? Sorry if its a silly question but I am confused!.